# Understand spy on with controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've been trying to spy a method defined in my controller as follows:

```
describe('My Controller', function(){

    var controller;

    beforeEach(module('MyModule'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
      controller = $controller('MyCtrl');
    }));

    it('My func should been called', function(){
        spyOn(controller, 'myFunc');
        expect(controller.myFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

and this it's my controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyModule')
        .controller('MyCtrl', ControllerFn);

    function ControllerFn(){
        var vm = this;

        vm.myFunc= myFunc;

        function myFunc(){
            console.log("it's been called");
        }
    }
})();
```

But the karma test failed. What I've been doing wrong?

EDIT: Simply I add a function call for my controller and works fine!

my it block should be :

```
it('My func should been called', function(){
    spyOn(controller, 'myFunc');
    controller.myFunc(); // Simpy call to my func       
    expect(controller.myFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: But your code does not call the method for the assertion to pass.

Comment: Ohh I finally understand how function the spyOn method. Thanks!